# Trying to build a docker file and getting a cryptic error - No inputs were found in config file '/tsconfig.json'

Tags: node.js, docker

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12

RUN set -x \
    rsyslog \
    bash \
    curl \
    wget \
    gettext \
    jq


WORKDIR .
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install -g typescript

RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build
WORKDIR ./src

RUN tsc --esModuleInterop index.ts
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
EXPOSE 8080
```

The include in my tsconfig.json looks as such:

```
"include": [
    "src/controllers/customer/UserAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/customer/NoticeAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/merchant/NoticeAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/customer/MerchantAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/merchant/MerchantAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/merchant/UserAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/customer/SearchAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/customer/ChatController.ts",
    "src/controllers/analytics/AnalyticsAPIController.ts",
    "src/controllers/StripeController.ts",
]
```

All of these files exist in their specified location when I sign into the created docker image.

So what exactly am I doing wrong here?

I am trying to build the index.js and .js files to run the application.

Comment: Are you sure you want `WORKDIR .`? That would be the top-level directory (i.e., `/`)  of the container.

Comment: I'll probably move it to a child directory once I've got this all working, right now I'm just testing to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

The error was because apparently the TypeScript linter requires a file in the root directory that is TypeScript.

I fixed it by doing the following:

Creating an empty file named "fake.ts"

And adding this to my tsconfig.json:

```
"include": [
    "./fake.ts",
    "./src/controllers/customer/UserAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/customer/NoticeAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/merchant/NoticeAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/customer/MerchantAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/merchant/MerchantAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/merchant/UserAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/customer/SearchAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/customer/ChatController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/analytics/AnalyticsAPIController.ts",
    "./src/controllers/StripeController.ts",
],
```